# OCaml: Check a list of records for membership

Tags: list, types, ocaml, record

If I have defined the following types:

```
type category = Noun | Verb | Adjective | Preposition;;
type transformation = {start: category; fin: category};;
```

What is the best way to answer the question "is the record where `start = Noun` in the list of type transformation?

Sort of like

```
let un = [{start= Noun; fin= Noun}; {start= Verb; fin= Adjective}];;    
List.mem {start = Noun; _} un;;
```

Except that syntax doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List.exists (fun x -> x.start = Noun) un
```

`List.mem` can be thought of as just a special case of `List.exists`, where `List.mem x ys` is equivalent to `List.exists ((=) x) ys`. So you can use `List.exists` for more general membership criteria.